# Quagga sample files not in the usual path

Tags: ubuntu

I tried to install quagga on Ubuntu. However, I am not finding the "sample" files in the usual path - `/usr/share/doc/quagga/examples/`

Infact, example folder does not exist at all.

I tried to install it using the command `apt-get install quagga`.

Answer (score 0):

To check the list of files in particular package you can use command like:

```
dpkg-query -L quagga
```